# Pass function to submitHandler callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, anonymous-function

I use `mainSubmitHandler` for multiple pages, and am willing to define it as a global variable if necessary.  `mainSubmitHandler`, however, requires some tweaking, and I am handling this by using `subSubmitHandler`.  Instead of having `subSubmitHandler` as another global variable, how can I pass it as an agrument to `mainSubmitHandler`?

```
var mainSubmitHandler=function(form) {
    //do a bunch of stuff
    subSubmitHandler(form);
};

var subSubmitHandler=function(form) {
    //do some stuff
};

// uses jQuery validation plugin
var validator=$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    submitHandler: mainSubmitHandler
});
```

Comment: use `bind`:  `mainSubmitHandler.bind(null, function)`

Comment: @Mouser  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here.

`bind` wraps around a function reference allowing you to pass the scope and variables to the targeted function:

> function.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

Parameters:

- thisArg: The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function when the bound function is called. The value is ignored if the bound function is constructed using the new operator.
- arg1, arg2, ...Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function.

<sub>*Source MDN*</sub>

```js
var mainSubmitHandler=function(form, callback) {
    //do a bunch of stuff
    if (typeof(callBack) != "undefined" && Object.prototype.toString.call(callBack) === "[object Function]") //sanity check. Check if callback is truly a function and exists.
    {
        callback(form);
    }
};

var subSubmitHandler=function(form) {
    //do some stuff
};

// uses jQuery validation plugin
var validator=$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    submitHandler: mainSubmitHandler.bind(null, form, subSubmitHandler); //first argument is set to null. This passes the this argument of the targeted function.
});
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I was missing.  I obviously can and will replace `subSubmitHandler` with an anonymous function. Let me test it out.  Thanks

Comment: Why not just `submitHandler: mainSubmitHandler(form, subSubmitHandler)` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille Both solutions will work. `bind` allows you to pass the scope. Also you need to return a function when setting `mainSubmitHandler(form, subSubmitHandler)` to the property `submitHandler` of the validator.

Comment: @user1032531, of course, I worked with your code, not going to delete arguments in your original code. You can leave it out, should work fine.

Comment: I tried leaving it out as I agree "of course".  But then, withing `mainSubmitHandler`, the first function received was `subSubmitHandler`, and the second was form.  Guess I didn't expect that but could work with it.  Thank you

Comment: After further testing, works perfect.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the fonction as additional argument :

```
var mainSubmitHandler=function(form, secondFunction) {
    //do a bunch of stuff
    secondFunction(form);
};

mainSubmitHandler(form, subSubmitHandler);
```

Is this what you mean?

You can pass an infinity of arguments to a function, all of them optional. You can even do this :

```
function doSomething(){ // not defining any arguments
    console.log( arguments); // will output everything you passed the function
}

doSomething( "Hello", someOtherFunction );
```

This works as well :

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2){ // defining 2 arguments, but will accept more if given
    console.log( arguments); // will output everything you passed the function
}

doSomething( "First", "Second", someFunction, "third");
```

This is why many strict people hate Javascript, and why I love it =)

Comment: If it works, yes this is what I mean.  I didn't know if I could do this, and will test it out.  Thank you

Comment: Backing up.  When defining `var validator`, how do I add `secondFunction`?  Do I do something like `submitHandler: mainSubmitHandler(function(){bla bla bla}):`

Comment: You can yes. Even though it's not very elegant or simple to maintain. If you don't want to expose your functions globally, store them in an object. I have updated my answer while you were writing your second comment, maybe it will help.

Comment: This won't provide a solution to the OP's problem. He wants to pass a variable to the `mainSubmitHandler` function that is invoked via the validator.

Comment: Not from what I understand. They said "Instead of having subSubmitHandler as another global variable, how can I pass it as an agrument to mainSubmitHandler?" So that's actually a function that has to be passed. Or the question is not clear at all.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,  I understand passing arguments to functions, and I `+1`'d you for hitting it home with your great examples.  I don't know, however, how your solution handles `$("#form1").validate({submitHandler: ???});`

Comment: Thanks for the +1 :) You can go `.validate({ submitHandler: mainSubmitHandler(subSubmitHandler) })` but that gets complicated. Mouser's solution is cleaner.