# JQuery validator call function from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validator plugin `jqueryvalidation` and having some problems calling a function from another js file.

In one file which is `theme.js` file i have a function calling preloader:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function loadAnimation() {
      $("#loader").show().animate({
        opacity: 1
      })
    }
});
```

I made it in function for the reasons that I can call function from different actions and buttons submit. Now I want to call the function from within the validator but I am getting an error of not defined and here is the validator which is located in another file `validator.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$( "#createForm" ).validate( {
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        rules: {
            offers: 'required',
            title: 'required',
       },
       submitHandler: function(form) {
            loadAnimation();
            form.submit();
       },
    } );
});
```

Now form submit works which means submitHandler works but i am getting an error `loadAnimation() is not defined`.

I made sure that `jquery`, `theme.js` are loaded before `validator.js` so I am probably missing something here but I can't figure out what and how to make `loadAnimation()` work from inside `submitHandler` function.

Comment: Is `loadAnimation` defined at the root level of the `theme.js` file? if it's inside another function or an object, it will get scoped off.

Comment: Oh sorry i am gonna correct that.

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue- if so, this might fix your wagon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182664/1772933

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue as pointed out in the comments. To achieve what you want you can extract the function definition outside of the ready function to use it in other files.

```
function loadAnimation() {
  $("#loader").show().animate({ opacity: 1 })
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // code that needs to fire when the page is ready
});
```

But this will pollute the global namespace so to solve that problem you need to think about creating modules and [importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) functions from other modules.